# Questions that you shouldn't forget to ask in a HR interview

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, human-resources

I will be having an interview with HR after the technical interview. Basically what kind of valid questions should I want to ask from them?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** You should preferably ask what *you* would like to know :)

What's important to you?  It could be anything like:

- Working hours
- Amenities
- Annual Leave
- Flexible arrangements
- Working conditions

What are the is important to you that would make *you* accept or reject a role?  These are the questions you should be asking :)

Answer (score 2):

As Jane answered, it depends on what you want to know in order to convince yourself to accept the offer.

I would ask for the following:

- Office Culture (Dress Code, Habits, etc come into this)
- Leave Structure
- Leadership Hierarchy
- Career ladder in my domain of work(or simply department)
- Appraisal policy
- Amenities

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above pension. If you are a cyclist perhaps are there showers at work.